# How can I spread array elements in parent object by jq?

Tags: jq

I want to transform following type of json obj

```json
[
{
  "A": "a",
  "Tags": [
    { "key":"x", "value":0},
    { "key":"y", "value":1},
  ]
},
{...}
]
```

to this, including Tags list on top

```json
[
{
  "A": "a",
  "x": 0,
  "y": 1
},
{...}
]
```

I try to use JQ but without result.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(. + (.Tags | from_entries) | del(.Tags))
```

---

Will [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) over all the objects in the array and:

- Convert `.Tags` to an object using [`from_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries)

  - This is added to the original object (`. + ()`)
- Delete the original `.Tags`

---

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "A": "a",
    "x": 0,
    "y": 1
  }
]
```

##### [Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LBsOC09OKiH)